# Adding a app.js file from resource folder not public

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, vue.js

I'm using `vue.js` for the first time and the files are located in `'Resources/Assets/js/app.js'`

How can I import that app.js file into my partials scripts. Currently the `assets()`points to the `public` folder and I need it like that.

When I try to move the asset folder into the public I get an error for 'multi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with any build tools like webpack, grunt, gulp, etc? Those are commonly used to bundle your application resources and move them to the desired destination, i.e. public in your case. I'd suggest reading some intro material to webpack as it is very often used in laravel + vuejs projects.

There are additional scripts in the package.json file that will run mom tasks too.

You will find `npm run dev` for local development and `npm run prod` for production.

Comment: I ran npm run dev and there isn't a new file I the public folder

Comment: Sorry my mistake! got it! now question: I have the chrome extension for vue.js and it still says vue.js not found? even though I have included it in my script too!

Comment: Are you certain the script has loaded on the page?

Comment: Got it working! it has to be wrapped in a div id #app. Correct?

Comment: is there a package in Atom that when I start typing lets say p (for props) it will automatically drop down a list?

Comment: Sure, Atom has several plugins for Vue support. Here is one: 

https://atom.io/packages/language-vue-component

Answer (score 0):

Try npm run dev
This will compile all your assets and you will get a single app.js file in the public folder. 
You can then use that app.js file in your HTML file

Comment: I ran npm run dev and there isn't a new file I the public folder

Comment: Sorry my mistake! got it! now question: I have the chrome extension for vue.js and it still says vue.js not found? even though I have included it in my script too!